# Android BaseAdapter, return item id

Tags: java, android, image-gallery, baseadapter

I am trying to get it so that when image 1 is showing, a textview shows its name

Here is my array of names

```
String[] soundcloudDates = { 
    "Image 1", 
    "Image 2", 
    "Image 3", 
    "Image 4",
};
```

and this is my BaseAdapter using the EcoGallery library from GitHub
all of the images scroll correctly but the output for their id is all over the place
more often than not it starts printing out position = 1;, then doesn't change until position = 3;

```
    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Not using convertView for simplicity. You should probably use it
        // in real application to get better performance.
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int resId;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.drawable.logo;
                            position = 0;
                            dateView.setText(soundcloudDates[position]);


            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.drawable.soundcloudtest;
                            position = 0;
                            dateView.setText(soundcloudDates[position]);


            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.drawable.logo;
                            position = 0;
                            dateView.setText(soundcloudDates[position]);


            break;
        case 3:
            resId = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                            position = 0;
                            dateView.setText(soundcloudDates[position]);

            break;
        default:
            resId = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(resId);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

I have tried placing the setText() in different places to no effect.

I dont understand what im doing wrong :( any help would be great

Comment: Why are you setting `position=0`?

Comment: that was left over from one of my attempts to pass position back out to a global variable to see if that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these :

```
 public int getCount() {
    return soundcloudDates.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return soundcloudDates[position];
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Not using convertView for simplicity. You should probably use it
    // in real application to get better performance.
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    String text = (String) getItem( position );
    int resId;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.drawable.logo;
            break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.drawable.soundcloudtest;
            break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.drawable.logo;
            break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            break;
    default:
        resId = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    }
    dateView.setText(text);
    imageView.setImageResource(resId);
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: nothing changed, as before the textview is changing but it appears to do so randomly. an image will set the feild as image 1 then when i return to it it will be image 4

Comment: Your dateView TextView doesn't appear to be initalised in your getView() method.

Comment: ok how do i initialise it? updated to your latest suggestion doesn't work. Thanks for your help by the way